# Error on java indexOf in android

Tags: java, android, indexof

in a block of my java code for an android project I'm trying to get position of a character in a string but application closes unexpectedly.

java code :

```
   public void onClickGet(View v){
    String getInput = editText.getText().toString();
    if(getInput.contains("(") ) {
        //inputEx(getInput);
        int a = getInput.indexOf("(");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @tnw the error is too long and this forum forces me to explain my problem more if my codes are longer!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Just tell us what the error is. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @tnw Ok, I'll work on my questions more, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Toast only accept string.. convert it to string first

```
try{
    int a = getInput.indexOf("(");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();  // this will show the error is if error caught
}
```

Comment: I think it does take an int, but expects it to be a valid resource id.

Comment: @ZeroOne my problem solved with your help, Thank you!